# r magick: Adding text to an image gives a font error

Tags: r, macos, fonts, imagemagick

I've recently upgraded to the macOS 11.6 on the M1 chip, and on my old intel-based macbook, I was able to place text on images, but now the following example,

```
library(magick)
tiger <- image_read_svg('http://jeroen.github.io/images/tiger.svg', width = 350)
img<-image_draw(tiger)
text(475, 450, "Some text")
dev.off()
```

gives the `Error in text.default(475, 450, "Framing items", cex = 3, col = "white") : rsession-arm64: UnableToReadFont` helvetica' @ error/annotate.c/RenderFreetype/1396` error in RStudio. I suspect this is related to the magick package.

I've uninstalled and reinstalled the R-app (R 4.1.1. gui 1.77 Big Sur ARM build (7985)) and RStudio (2021.09 build 351).

Does anyone have a clue to what could be done?

Thanks, Jon